# Drag and drop file on file input field

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

So I have a drop event on which I am able to call

```
fileInput.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
```

The code above works, however when I am trying to write that code in typescript I am assigning a type of HTMLInputElement to the fileInput variable. After which fileInput.files because a readonly property.

```
fileInput: HTMLInputElement;
fileInput.files = e.dataTransfer.files; // now is readonly
```

I mean one way to get around this is to put a type of any for fileInput but is this the right way?

Comment: Isn't the drag & drop on input with file type a native feature on the browsers ?

Comment: @Seblor I am doing a custom one, hiding the input field and adding a preview for the image

Comment: The files property of an input element is supposed to be readonly. See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_files.asp. But if your code works, and you want to bypass the typescript error, casting to `any` is probably the simplest solution. But I would reconsider trying to write to that property in the first place.